# Converting Photoshop .CSH files to .SVG or .EPS. Possible?

Tags: conversion, adobe-photoshop, vector-graphics, svg, eps

excuse my total ignorance, but does anyone know if it might be possible to convert Photoshop's .CSH files (Custom Shape Format) to standard .SVG or .EPS files? They're both Vector shapes, so it seems a little annoying that the information is stored in such a weird format.

I'm guessing the answer is probably "not a chance", but I thought I'd ask :)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Photoshop installed?

If so you can "Save As" .EPS format directly.

Unless there's a plugin it doesn't appear that Photoshop saves to .SVG "out of the box".

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You can't save an EPS, only a Photoshop EPS... Do you know what the difference is (assuming there is one)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure EPS and Photoshop EPS are the same thing.

Comment: Got a solution for someone who doesn't want to pay for PhotoShop?

Answer (score 1):

In PhotoShop (PS), with your Custom Shapes already saved to Presets > Custom Shapes Folder.

Go to Custom Shapes in PS then create your shapes in a new PS file (they are now Work Paths) then Export Paths to Illustrator.

Open that .ai file in Illustrator and finally you can then save as an EPS.

Answer (score 0):

In Photoshop, right click on the custom shape and choose **Export as > SVG**.
Or, if you have a CSH file, you can use this online tool to convert [CSH to SVG](https://www.photoshopsupply.com/vector/csh-to-svg) automatically.